# add a icon to image button

Tags: android, xml

I have some Image Buttons and I want to add some icon (red circle in example):

[image]

But I don't know how to align this little icon. I have one selector for the Button (used background):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/round_button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/round_button_pressed" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_button" /> <!-- default -->
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@drawable/round_button_deactivated" />
    <item android:state_activated="false" android:drawable="@drawable/round_button_deactivated" />
</selector>
```

and one shape.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="@color/button_main"
        android:endColor="@color/button_main"
        android:angle="270" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0px"
        android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

does anyone know where I should ad my icon drawable to get this little icon under my imagebutton?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a custom drawable class that allows you to draw your image and anything else you want on it as well, and then set that class to be your ImageButton's image.

```
public class StackedImage extends Drawable {

    private Drawable _drawable;

    /* CONSTRUCTOR */
    public StackedImage(Drawable drawable) {
        super();
        _drawable = drawable;
        invalidateSelf();
    }


    /* ON DRAW */
    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        // Draw main image

        _drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth, canvas.getHeight);
        _drawable.draw(canvas);

        // Draw anything else you may want

        // E.g. canvas.drawCircle(...)
    }

    @Override public void setAlpha(@IntRange(from = 0, to = 255) int alpha) {}
    @Override public void setColorFilter(@Nullable ColorFilter colorFilter) {}
    @Override public int getOpacity() { return PixelFormat.UNKNOWN; }
}
```

You can even have multiple images be part of your background simply by passing in more drawables to the constructor and changing their bounds to the location you want.

Then in your MainActivity (or wherever you're dealing with your ImageButton), do something like the following:

```
Drawable icon = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon, null)
StackedImage stackedImage = new StackedImage(icon);

ImageButton myButton = findViewById(R.id.button)
myButton.setImageDrawable(stackedImage);
```

Hope that helps!